# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in scss.inc.php on line 1753

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, sass

While dealing with WordPress i encountered the error  **Trying to access array offset on value of type null in scss.inc.php on line 1753**

```
    protected function sortArgs($prototype, $args) {
        $keyArgs = array();
        $posArgs = array();

        foreach ($args as $arg) {
            list($key, $value) = $arg;
            $key = $key[1]; //LINE 1753******
            if (empty($key)) {
                $posArgs[] = $value;
            } else {
                $keyArgs[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        if (!isset($prototype)) return $posArgs;

        $finalArgs = array();
        foreach ($prototype as $i => $names) {
            if (isset($posArgs[$i])) {
                $finalArgs[] = $posArgs[$i];
                continue;
            }
```

[Screenshot of the wordpress log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8XOB.jpg)

Comment: The error message is pretty specific about the error. `$key` is null but you're using it as an array.

Comment: you could fix using the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) (PHP7): `$key = $key[1] ?? ''; //LINE 1753******`